# how to send mails in python using outlook web app

Tags: python, smtp

I want to send mails to many people with python but without using smtp link
like how this guy is doing : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6I_YifPid4
can anyone tell how can I recieve this results or if anyone has same type of software as shown in the video tell that too please..

Answer (score 2):

you could use a library like [redmail](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/config.html) to send emails
this is an example of how to use it:

```
from redmail import outlook

outlook.username = YOUR_USERNAME
outlook.password = YOUR PASSWORD

outlook.send(receivers, subject, text, attachments)
```